# Python3.12.2 not getting updated in Ubuntu successfully

Tags: 22.04, python

I'm a new user in Ubuntu, new in Linux domain. I have python3.10 as the system version. I have been trying to update to 3.12.2. I downloaded the python3.12.2 file from [python.org](https://www.python.org/). After that, I followed some steps which I think that entirely messed my system. I am sharing those steps if this help anybody in future can avoid.

Step 1:

```
tar -xf Python-3.10.2.tgz   # Replace "Python-3.10.2.tgz" with the name of the downloaded file
cd Python-3.10.2
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

First Error :

```
configure: error: in `/home/user/Downloads/Python-3.12.2':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

Step 2:
To resolve it, I did the following:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Step 3:

```
cd /path/to/Python-3.12.2 
./configure
make 
sudo make install
```

Error: After the make command, everything went to hell!

Step 4:
To resolve the above issue, I tried this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libssl-dev
```

Error: Nothing resolved. No luck

Step 5:
Tried to update interpreter from pycharm. No luck.
Meanwhile, my pip and python3 returning two separate locations!

After all these, my machine was going all different directions. Reinstalled ubuntu again and back to 3.10

Comment: Stop after the make, don't do make install.  The last thing you want to do is change your system default python.  You can still run python3.12 from the directory you build it in, change some env variables if necessary for projects to pick up the python you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Use a virtual environment to resolve your issue.**

- Updating Python in Ubuntu can cause compatibility issues with system components and applications. Ubuntu relies on specific Python versions for its internal processes, and updating Python could disrupt these dependencies.
- **Use a Python Version Manager**: Consider using a Python version manager like Pyenv or asdf to manage multiple Python versions on your system. These tools allow you to install and switch between different Python versions easily, and you can create virtual environments with any installed Python version.

Let me know if any further information is needed.